# Number of interval of seq without for loop

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a dataframe with dates and I used `seq()` between the lowest and the highest date by year.

Dataframe :

```
     daysOfStop dateConsult
 1:         NA  2002-11-17
 2:         NA  2003-11-03
 3:         NA  2004-12-16
 4:         NA  2006-01-31
 5:         NA  2006-01-31
 6:         NA  2003-02-05
 7:         NA  2003-09-29
 8:         NA  2005-08-01
 9:         NA  2005-08-01
10:         NA  2005-08-01
```

Results of `seq()` :

```
"2002-11-17" "2003-11-17" "2004-11-17" "2005-11-17"
```

What I would like to do it to create a new column in which the values are defined by the intervals of `seq()` without for looping (that takes a lot of time since I have more than 120 000 rows).

So :
between `"2002-11-17"` and `"2003-11-17"`, it's year number 1 (first interval);
between `"2003-11-17"` and `"2004-11-17"`, it's year number 2 (second interval)
and so on.

Results expected :

```
     daysOfStop dateConsult numYear
 1:         NA  2002-11-17    1
 2:         NA  2003-11-03    1
 3:         NA  2004-12-16    3
 4:         NA  2006-01-31    4
 5:         NA  2006-01-31    4
 6:         NA  2003-02-05    1
 7:         NA  2003-09-29    1
 8:         NA  2005-08-01    3
 9:         NA  2005-08-01    3
10:         NA  2005-08-01    3
```

Data :

```
structure(list(daysOfStop = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    dateConsult = structure(c(12008, 12359, 12768, 13179, 13179, 
    12088, 12324, 12996, 12996, 12996), class = "Date")), .Names = c("daysOfStop", 
"dateConsult"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000006360788>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `findInterval`

```
dt1[, numYear := findInterval(dateConsult, seq(min(dateConsult), 
                       max(dateConsult), "1 year"))]
```

Comment: That's the function I was looking for. Very powerful. Thanks !